# Showing Nothing in created PDF using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

i am trying to export my HTML page to PDF using iTextSharp lib. firstly i am trying to print table which is in my Aspx page.PDF is created successfully but there nothing in PDF. 
i am using this code below :

```
protected void btnExportToPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        btnExportToPdf.Visible = false;


        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        exportTable.RenderControl(hw);

        //this.Page.RenderControl(hw);

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I'm not too seasoned, but the problem to me looks like you are never actually writing the strings to the file.  I see a few different string objects you initialize, and I see you adding the HTML to it, but I never see you actually write them to the PDF. This is my usual process for parsing HTML to PDF, maybe you can look at it, and see what you are missing.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder store = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
string line;

     while ((line = htmlReader.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
       store.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
     }

string html = store.ToString();
FileStream stream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 15, 15, 35, 25);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
document.Open();
System.Collections.Generic.List<IElement> htmlarraylist = new List<IElement>(HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(html), new StyleSheet()));

     foreach (IElement element in htmlarraylist)
     {
        document.Add(element);
     }

document.Close();
```

That was what jumped out to me at least, was the fact that it doesn't look like you actually write the generated text to the PDF.  I hope this helps.